# how to translate "Are you <adjective>?"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Example, does "are you whimsical?" translates in to "Sie sind wunderlich?"

Also, does gender matters for the word "you" and verb "to be"?

Comment: Was sagt denn das Wörterbuch? Nur er/sie/es (3. Pers. Sing.) hat ein Geschlecht, das sich aber nicht auf's Verb auswirkt (er/sie/es geht/ging/wird gehen...). Und das Verb gehört an den Anfang: "Sind Sie wunderlich? Kaufen Sie Marzipan? Spielen Sie Fußball?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you can translate

> Are you *adjective*?

as

> Bist Du *Adjektiv*?

For example,

> Are you young?

translates to

> Bist Du jung?

The grammatical gender doesn't have an influence in the second person singular. But be aware that (like in English) you have to switch the subject and predicate in a question:

> You are young -> Are you young?
>
> Du bist jung -> Bist Du jung?

And as a side note, "wunderlich" might not be the best translation for "whimsical". "wunderlich" has a stronger negative connotation, for example in the range of "quaint", "odd" or "strange". A better translation for "whimsical" might be "launenhaft".

Comment: You wouldn't capitalize "du" in the middle of a sentence unless you're trying to be polite. For instance, with "Sie".

Comment: And if you're talking to somebody, like in the second person singular, why not be polite ;) Seriously, that's probably an outdated habit of mine, but I'm *whimsical* enough not to change it ;)

Comment: For sure. Just saying it's how it is in common usage. If you were being so polite, you'd never use "du" at all ;)